# "Tell, don't ask": what is the difference between a non-void method and a getter?

Tags: c#, properties, methods

How might I justify using a non-void method while not using any property getters?  What is the distinction between these two concepts such that getters are evil but non-void methods are acceptable?

EDIT:

```
int CalculateSomething();

int Calculation { get; }
```

The fact that I can change the signature of `CalculateSomething` and pass values into it if I wanted to completely slipped my mind.  So my question is changed to: Is the fundamental distinction between getters and non-void methods that arguments can be passed into non-void methods?

Comment: Uh, perhaps include example function signatures for us?

Comment: Care to post some code? As is, I can't make heads or tails of this.

Comment: I think there is a real question here, so not voting to close.  Let's give OP a few moments to clarify?

Comment: I've never heard that getters are evil.  Without getters how would a well encapsulated object describe itself to the system?

Comment: @wheaties - parsing docstrings? ;)

Comment: Is this one of those my-boss/peer/wife/dog-reviewed-my-code-and-wants-me-to-replace-an-accessor-with-a-method-so-I-need-a-smart-SO-bod-to-write-a-witty-retort-I-can-beat-them-with questions?

Comment: I got fedup of waiting for expansion :P

Comment: @wheaties One might consider a getter "evil" if it has a side effect.  A getter shouldn't modify the state of the object, with perhaps an exception for lazy loading.  A modifying getter is just bad implementation.  Getters are not, in of themselves, evil.

Comment: Come on, people! It's only been 20 minutes. Give the OP a chance!

Comment: @John: Not only that, but I think OP clarified his question into something answerable. I voted to reopen.

Comment: Too bad that it was closed. Being wary of accessors is a rule of thumb that's based on good design judgment (about encapsulation, division of responsibilities, etc) but that's too often misunderstood as something that can be applied mechanically by looking at method signatures. My reading is that Sam knows that this mechanical way of expressing the rule is unsatisfactory, and is asking for clarification of the underlying thought process. Good question, difficult one to answer, shouldn't be dismissed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't the big difference, that you can't pass a variable to a getter?

a function:

```
private int Getyear(datetime date) { }
```

a property:

```
private DateTime GetDate {
    get {return _date};
}
```

you can't do that with a getter property can you?

Comment: I would still like to know from Sam in what context the getters are evil?

Comment: You can pass a variable to the indexer property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft has [guidance for choosing between properties and methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054.aspx).

- Consider using a property if the member represents a logical attribute of the type.
- Do use a property, rather than a method, if the value of the property is stored in the process memory and the property would just provide access to the value.
- Do use a method, rather than a property, in the following situations.

  - The operation is orders of magnitude slower than a field set would be. If you are even considering providing an asynchronous version of an operation to avoid blocking the thread, it is very likely that the operation is too expensive to be a property. In particular, operations that access the network or the file system (other than once for initialization) should most likely be methods, not properties.
  - The operation is a conversion, such as the Object.ToString method.
  - The operation returns a different result each time it is called, even if the parameters do not change. For example, the NewGuid method returns a different value each time it is called.
  - The operation has a significant and observable side effect. Note that populating an internal cache is not generally considered an observable side effect.
  - The operation returns a copy of an internal state (this does not include copies of value type objects returned on the stack).
  - The operation returns an array.

Comment: Some of Microsoft's points could be better clarified.  Something like `Guid.NewGuid()` has the side-effect of deliberately causing future calls to `Guid.NewGuid()` to return different values in a way that other function calls would not, whereas something like "DateTime.Now" does not (the fact that the latter takes time to execute may affect future calls to `DateTime.Now`, but not in a fashion any different from any other function that took the same amount of time to execute).  As for the last two points, I would consolidate both as "the operation returns a new object instance".